# Как в классе объявить переменную/свойство, хранящую ссылку на объект?

Tags: c#

Как в классе объявить поле/свойство ссылочного типа? Пример:

```
class Test
{
    public Test Parent;
    public Test Child;
    public string Value;
    public void New() { Parent = this; Child = new Test(); }
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы Parent хранила ссылку на this, а не значение?

Comment: То есть у вас какой то источник информации - что ни о чем не говорит. И вы оттуда что то вытягиваете - то, чем занимаются 99% приложений, что то откуда то вытягивают. И вам зачем то надо дерево - это ваши мысли по решению проблемы, но сама проблема не ясна. Я думаю, вам стоит более подробно описать вашу проблему с примерами кода, который не работает как надо. А сейчас ваше описание настолько расплывчатое, что не понятна не только проблема, но и вообще суть вашей задачи.

Comment: "с примерами кода, который не работает как надо" Я пока не определился с логикой. А вопрос я дал чёткий: как в классе объявить переменную/свойство, хранящую не значение объекта, а ссылку на него?

Comment: хорошо, вот вам четкий ответ: любое поле ссылочного типа может хранить ссылку на объект.

Comment: Я не спрашивал, что там чего может. Повторяю в третий раз: как в классе (не абстрактном) **объявить** переменную/свойство, хранящую не значение объекта, а ссылку на него?

Comment: `как в классе (не абстрактном) объявить переменную/свойство, хранящую не значение объекта, а ссылку на него`. Вы не можете определить переменную в классе. Но вы можете определить свойство или поле. Чтобы свойство или поле хранило ссылку на объект. оно должно быть ссылочного типа. Синтаксис объявления поля ссылочного типа ничем не отличается от объявления поля значимого типа.

Comment: Вот инфа [по полям](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields), вот инфа по [ссылочным](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) типам.

Comment: Спасибо, обновил вопрос.

Comment: @LSMR, ваш пример делает ровно то, что вы и хотите и о чем спрашиваете. В типе Parent будет храниться ссылка, а не значение. Могу привести пример, который это подтвердит. Поэтому ваш вопрос и не понимают. Или вы что-то не можете объяснить или не так понимаете.

Comment: @Alex спасибо, распутали.